# change background color of RadioButton in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, radio-button

I have a radio button in flex and wanna change background color of its text to some color
but I didn't find any solution for this problem.

EDIT :
NOTICE: I want some ( not all) of radio button with some conditions in a radio button group, have different color

Is there any solution for this?

EDIT :
code of my project

MyItemRenderer.mxml

```
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
            xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" dataChange="onDataChange()" >
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import avmplus.constantXml;

    import ir.fanap.bizint.ui.flex.event.MyAdvancedListEvent;
    import ir.fanap.bizint.ui.flex.skin.MyRadioButtonSkin;

    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    private function onDataChange():void {
        changeColorForMultiCube();
    }

    private function changeColorForMultiCube():void {
    if (data['color'] != null ) {
        box.setStyle("skinClass","MySkin");
    }
    else{
    box.setStyle("SkinClass","RadioButtonSkin");//default skin for radio button
    }
    }
]]></fx:Script>
<s:states>
    <s:State name="normal" />
    <s:State name="hovered" />
    <s:State name="selected" />
</s:states>

<s:RadioButton id="box" change="onDataChange()"/>
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

MySkin.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fx:Metadata>
<![CDATA[
    /**
     * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
     */
    [HostComponent("spark.components.RadioButton")]
]]>
</fx:Metadata>

<fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
    /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized.
       For button, the graphics are colorized but the label is not. */
    static private const exclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay", "dot"];

    /**
     * @private
     */
    override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

    /* Define the symbol fill items that should be colored by the "symbolColor" style. */
    static private const symbols:Array = ["dotFill"];

    /**
     * @private
     */
    override public function get symbolItems():Array {return symbols};

    /**
     * @private
     */
    override protected function initializationComplete():void
    {
        useChromeColor = true;
        super.initializationComplete();
    }
</fx:Script>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    /**
     * @private
     */    
    private static const focusExclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay"];

    /**
     *  @private
     */
    override public function get focusSkinExclusions():Array { return focusExclusions;};
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:states>
    <s:State name="up" />
    <s:State name="over" stateGroups="overStates" />
    <s:State name="down" stateGroups="downStates" />
    <s:State name="disabled" stateGroups="disabledStates" />
    <s:State name="upAndSelected" stateGroups="selectedStates" />
    <s:State name="overAndSelected" stateGroups="overStates, selectedStates" />
    <s:State name="downAndSelected" stateGroups="downStates, selectedStates" />
    <s:State name="disabledAndSelected" stateGroups="disabledStates, selectedStates" />
</s:states>

<s:Rect width="{labelDisplay.width}" height="{labelDisplay.height}" left="18" right="0" top="3" bottom="3" verticalCenter="2">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="0xDAC1C3" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>
<s:Label id="labelDisplay"
         textAlign="start"
         verticalAlign="middle"
         maxDisplayedLines="1"
         left="18" right="0" top="3" bottom="3" verticalCenter="2" />
</s:SparkSkin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I am posting answer again for your ease. But I will request you to come out of your comfort level and search things. You will find many other important things in the process of finding your answer.

Below are the codes used.

**Application.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

            private var arrSource:Array = [{label:"Button1", color:0xDAC1C3},
                                            {label:"Button2", color:0xDAC1C3},
                                            {label:"Button3"}, {label:"Button4", color:0xDAC1C3}, {label:"Button5", color:0xDAC1C3},
                                            {label:"Button6"}, {label:"Button7", color:0xDAC1C3}, {label:"Button8", color:0xDAC1C3},
                                            {label:"Button9"},{label:"Button10", color:0xDAC1C3},{label:"Button11", color:0xDAC1C3}];

            private var arrCol:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(arrSource);
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:List id="lstBtns" dataProvider="{arrCol}" itemRenderer="MyItemRenderer">

    </s:List>
</s:Application>
```

**MyItemRenderer.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
                autoDrawBackground="true" dataChange="onDataChange()">

    <fx:Script><![CDATA[
        import mx.core.UIComponent;

        import spark.components.RadioButtonGroup;
        import spark.skins.spark.RadioButtonSkin;

        private static var rdoBtnGrp:RadioButtonGroup = new RadioButtonGroup();

        private function onDataChange():void {
            changeColorForMultiCube();
        }

        private function changeColorForMultiCube():void {
            if (data['color'] != null ) {
                box.setStyle("skinClass",MySkin2);
            }
            else{
                box.setStyle("SkinClass",RadioButtonSkin);//default skin for radio button
            }
        }
    ]]></fx:Script>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="normal" />
        <s:State name="hovered" />
        <s:State name="selected" />
    </s:states>

    <s:RadioButton id="box" change="onDataChange()" label="{data.label}" group="{rdoBtnGrp}"/>

</s:ItemRenderer>
```

**MySkin2.mxml**
Don't Delete anything which is pre-written when you are making skin unless you have specific reason to do so. I have added in this skin only `Rect` with `id="bgColor"` before the `labelDisplay`. The fill color is responsible for radio button's background color. If you want to set this color dynamic then you need to create a class extending `RadioButton` and define [SkinPart] there. Please see [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex4_skinning.html) and [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/dynamic_skin_parts.html)

```
<!--

    ADOBE SYSTEMS INCORPORATED
    Copyright 2008 Adobe Systems Incorporated
    All Rights Reserved.

    NOTICE: Adobe permits you to use, modify, and distribute this file
    in accordance with the terms of the license agreement accompanying it.

-->

<!--- The default skin class for a Spark RadioButton component.  

       @see spark.components.RadioButton
       @see spark.components.RadioButtonGroup

      @langversion 3.0
      @playerversion Flash 10
      @playerversion AIR 1.5
      @productversion Flex 4
-->
<s:SparkSkin xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:fb="http://ns.adobe.com/flashbuilder/2009" alpha.disabledStates="0.5">

    <fx:Metadata>
    <![CDATA[ 
        /** 
         * @copy spark.skins.spark.ApplicationSkin#hostComponent
         */
        [HostComponent("spark.components.RadioButton")]
    ]]>
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <fx:Script fb:purpose="styling">
        /* Define the skin elements that should not be colorized. 
           For button, the graphics are colorized but the label is not. */
        static private const exclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay", "dot"];

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override public function get colorizeExclusions():Array {return exclusions;}

        /* Define the symbol fill items that should be colored by the "symbolColor" style. */
        static private const symbols:Array = ["dotFill"];

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override public function get symbolItems():Array {return symbols};

        /**
         * @private
         */
        override protected function initializationComplete():void
        {
            useChromeColor = true;
            super.initializationComplete();
        }
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        /** 
         * @private 
         */     
        private static const focusExclusions:Array = ["labelDisplay"];

        /**
         *  @private
         */
        override public function get focusSkinExclusions():Array { return focusExclusions;};
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:states>
        <s:State name="up" />
        <s:State name="over" stateGroups="overStates" />
        <s:State name="down" stateGroups="downStates" />
        <s:State name="disabled" stateGroups="disabledStates" />
        <s:State name="upAndSelected" stateGroups="selectedStates" />
        <s:State name="overAndSelected" stateGroups="overStates, selectedStates" />
        <s:State name="downAndSelected" stateGroups="downStates, selectedStates" />
        <s:State name="disabledAndSelected" stateGroups="disabledStates, selectedStates" />
    </s:states>

    <s:Group verticalCenter="0" width="13" height="13">
        <!-- drop shadow -->
        <s:Ellipse left="-1" top="-1" right="-1" bottom="-1">
            <s:stroke>
                <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                   color.downStates="0xFFFFFF"
                                   alpha="0.011"
                                   alpha.downStates="0" />
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" 
                                   color.downStates="0xFFFFFF" 
                                   alpha="0.121"
                                   alpha.downStates="0.57" />
                </s:LinearGradientStroke>
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Ellipse>

        <!-- fill -->
        <s:Ellipse left="1" top="1" right="1" bottom="1">
            <s:fill>
                <s:LinearGradient rotation="90">
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" 
                                   color.overStates="0xBBBDBD" 
                                   color.downStates="0xAAAAAA" 
                                   alpha="0.85" />
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" 
                                   color.overStates="0x9FA0A1" 
                                   color.downStates="0x929496" 
                                   alpha="0.85" />
                </s:LinearGradient>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Ellipse>

        <!-- fill highlight -->
        <s:Path data="M 1 6 Q 2 2 6 1 Q 11 2 12 6 h -9">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="0xFFFFFF" alpha="0.33" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Path>

        <!-- layer 6: highlight stroke (all states except down) -->
        <s:Ellipse left="1" right="1" top="1" bottom="1">
            <s:stroke>
                <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" color.downStates="0x939393" alpha.overStates="0.22" />
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xD8D8D8" color.downStates="0xB1B1B1" alpha.overStates="0.22" />
                </s:LinearGradientStroke>
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Ellipse>
        <s:Rect left="5" top="1" right="5" height="1">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="0xFFFFFF" 
                            color.downStates="0x939393"
                            alpha.overStates="0.22" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>

        <!-- border - put on top of the fill so it doesn't disappear when scale is less than 1 -->
        <s:Ellipse left="0" top="0" right="0" bottom="0">
            <s:stroke>
                <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90" weight="1">
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.70" />
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0x000000" alpha="0.80" />
                </s:LinearGradientStroke>
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Ellipse>

        <!-- dot -->
        <!--- Defines the appearance of the RadioButton's dot. To customize the appearance of the dot, create a custom RadioButtonSkin class. -->
        <s:Path left="4" top="4" includeIn="selectedStates" id="dot" itemCreationPolicy="immediate"
                data="M 2.5 0 Q 4.5 0.5 5 2.5 Q 4.5 4.5 2.5 5 Q 0.5 4.5 0 2.5 Q 0.5 0.5 2.5 0">
            <s:fill>
                <!--- @private
                      Defines the appearance of the dot's fill. The default color is 0x000000. The default alpha is .9. -->
                <s:SolidColor id="dotFill" color="0" alpha="0.9" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Path>
        <s:Path left="4" top="7" includeIn="selectedStates" 
                data="M 0 0 Q 0.5 2 2.5 2.0 Q 3.5 2.0 4 0">
            <s:stroke>
                <s:LinearGradientStroke>
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha="0.3" />
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha="0.7" />
                    <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha="0.3" />
                </s:LinearGradientStroke>
            </s:stroke>
        </s:Path>
    </s:Group>

    <!-- Label -->
    <!---  @copy spark.components.supportClasses.ButtonBase#labelDisplay -->
    <s:Rect id="bgColor" left="18" right="0" top="3" bottom="3" verticalCenter="2"
            >
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xDAC1C3" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Label id="labelDisplay"
             textAlign="start"
             verticalAlign="middle"
             maxDisplayedLines="1"
             left="18" right="0" top="3" bottom="3" verticalCenter="2" />

</s:SparkSkin>
```

Comment: Well done Asad and @sami, Asad is right, online resources about Flex developing are numerous and you'll learn plenty of new things/best practices. AS3/Flex Livedocs are really good! Just use it ;)

Comment: Thanks @Asad ... Asad and Nicolas I search a lot but unfortunately i am in a country that's in boycott by alot of sites such as Adobe. :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Flex 3 but in Flex 4, it can be done in the following way.

1) Create an MXML skin with HostComponent as `spark.components.RadioButton`.
2)Create a graphics `Rect` before `labelDisplay` of radio button, which is of same dimension & position as the `labelDisplay` is.

```
<s:Rect width="{labelDisplay.width}" height="{labelDisplay.height}" left="18" right="0" top="3" bottom="3" verticalCenter="2">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0xDAC1C3" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Label id="labelDisplay"
             textAlign="start"
             verticalAlign="middle"
             maxDisplayedLines="1"
             left="18" right="0" top="3" bottom="3" verticalCenter="2" />
```

3) Use this skin in the Spark `RadioButton` created in Application.

```
<s:RadioButton id="rdo" label="Programming in Actionscript" fontSize="20" x="100" y="100" skinClass="skinRdoBtn"/>
```

Comment: sorry @Asad Im beginner in flex and don't understand how to create this skin!!

Comment: To create a new skin, you just have to go to File->New->MXML Skin or, using Flash Builder, you type skinClass as an attribute of your RadioButton, you CTRL+Space and it will offer you a 'Create skin' option

Comment: To apply this skin to some specific RadioButtons, you add the newly created skin as value of the skinClass property of those targeted buttons. You can do that via CSS too. I recommend you to read the docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSC8DB0C28-F7A6-48ff-9899-7957415A0A49.html

Comment: @Nicolas Are u sure it is working? because i try it but my application hanged and didn't do anything!!

Comment: @Nicolas : your link doesn't open for me! :(

Comment: @sami : which flex builder and sdk you are using?

Comment: @sami : That's usually the way I use to create/apply skins. I'll ask the same question as Asad: which FB and SDK version are used? Regarding the docs, you may google "spark skin" and you'll be able to find relevant links. I didn't expect the link not to work.

Comment: flex builder 4.5.1 and SDK 1.6

Comment: I could create skin but the problem is how to set this skin to some of RadioButtons ? I have ItemRenderer for RadioButton and should set this in this ItemRenderer

Comment: Flex 1.6 or 4.6? To apply the skin, you should have a 'skinClass' property in your <s:RadioButton> tag. Just assign your Skin Class qualified name (e.g. com.example.skins.MyCustomRadioButtonSkin.mxml) to this property

Comment: @sami : will you please share your code so that we can help you more.

Comment: @Nicolas I have it and do this but This work apply this skin to all radiobuttons not to some special of them

Comment: Just add the skinClass property to the specific RadioButtons you want to have a background. Otherwise, you can set the styleName property to these RadioButtons (e.g. styleName="customRadioButton") and in a <fx:Style> tag or in a CSS file you can write .customRadioButton { skinClass:ClassReference("com.example.skins.MyCustomRadioButtonSkin"); } That should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
myRadBtnId.setStyle("backgroundColor","0x00FF00");
```

(or)

```
myRadBtnId.setStyle("backgroundColor", #E8E8E8);
```

Comment: It doesn't change the background of its text, It just change the color of radio Button not its label!

Comment: I don't know how to upload picture here :(

Comment: I want all of a special row in radio button group get special color

Comment: I do this but it just change color of the its text not background color of it

Comment: @sami, I don't have FLEX environment here. So i am assuming things. Sorry. Can you give it a final try ?